# The UI thread looper MessageQueue processing stops at some point

Tags: android, android-looper

I'm working on a softkeyboard and many clients have complained that the application (keyboard) freezes at some point and they are unable to use it anymore until they kill the app.

After performing a dump of a handler associated with the main looper, I've noticed that the `MessageQueue` contains more than two thousand messages and the first one (that obviously blocks the processing) is a `barrier`.

Here is how the dump file looks like:

```
MainHandlerPrefixHandler (android.os.Handler) {3ff4640} @ 263606865
MainHandlerPrefix  Looper (main, tid 2) {989979}
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 0: { when=-6m23s60ms barrier=79218 }
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 1: { when=-6m23s60ms callback=my.package.MyService$6 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler }
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 2: { when=-6m23s60ms callback=my.package.-$$Lambda$MyService$1$ubKmTRTmp1KgOJNPNWqMqGvEn4w target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler }
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 3: { when=-6m23s60ms callback=my.package.-$$Lambda$MyService$j8NCLWjGRK01foVLc7iUIBP0CK4 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler }
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 4: { when=-6m22s762ms callback=my.package.-$$Lambda$MyService$3PQrgbrUtIie519YhF12lIH8KUQ target=android.os.Handler }
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 5: { when=-6m22s761ms callback=my.package.MyService$5 target=android.os.Handler }
...
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 2232: { when=-32ms callback=my.package.-$$Lambda$MyService$3PQrgbrUtIie519YhF12lIH8KUQ target=android.os.Handler }
MainHandlerPrefix    Message 2233: { when=0 callback=my.package.-$$Lambda$MyService$ct9EhzRGhNjeTqThcka4z4DVWy0 target=android.os.Handler }
MainHandlerPrefix    (Total messages: 2234, polling=true, quitting=false)
```

As you can see from the dump, the "barrier" message has been in the queue for more than six minutes.

Here is how the main handler is initialized:

```
private void initMainHandler() {
    mainHandler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper());
}
```

And here is how the `Runnable` is being sent to the main lopper:

```
 private void runOnUiThread(Runnable r, String message) {

        try {
            if (Thread.currentThread() == getMainHandler().getLooper().getThread()) {
                r.run();
            } else {
                getMainHandler().post(r);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "", e);
        }
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
public void loadKeyboard() {
     runOnUiThread(() -> {
                containerFacade.requestLayout();
                containerFacade.layoutOverlay();
     }, "example");
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this issue, I just got a log from the client who has complained about it.

Do you have any ideas what could cause this locking? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the `Looper.removeSyncBarrier(int token)`, where the `token` is the message (`barrier`) value from the `MessageQueue` with index '0' (from the dump), is never called, thus the thread associated with the loop is locked and the app hangs.

Comment: Could you post full code of your classes? Based on description above the it is not an ANR because user should get alert 5 seconds later. It seems more like infinite keyboard opening calling or something like this.

Comment: How do you call runOnUiThread method, please show us that?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the response. Yes, it's definitely not an ANR as there is nothing in the play console reports and the user can still type, just the UI components are frozen (including the candidates view).
Unfortunately, I'm dealing with the "God service" class with more than 3000 lines of code and I'm not sure it would be helpful to post it here (and I'm not allowed to share the code anyway...). Your response gave me the idea of where I could dig, though.

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi I added the example, but there isn't anything mysterious here, just passing a Runnable instance to the method.

Comment: i suggest that you use EventBus instead. try it and let me no . best wishes

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi Unfortunately, there are no resources for any major refactoring, I'll have to deal with what I have now...thanks!